# How to have a Published var of a view type with a view builder?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this class:

```
final class DialogPresentation: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isPresented = false
    @Published var dialogContent: DialogContent?
    
    func show(content: DialogContent?) {
        
        if let presentDialog = content {
            dialogContent = presentDialog
            isPresented = true
        } else {
            isPresented = false
        }
    }
}
```

This is what `DialogContent` looks like:

```
enum DialogContent: View {
    
    case contentDetail01(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, title: String)
    case contentDetail02(isPresented: Binding<Bool>)


    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        switch self {
        case .contentDetail01(let isPresented, let title):
            DemoDialogContent01(isPresented: isPresented, title: title)
        case .contentDetail02(let isPresented):
            DemoDialogContent02(isPresented: isPresented)
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to change `DialogContent` to this:

```
struct DynamicDialogView<Content: View>: View {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    let dialogContent: Content
    
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>,
         @ViewBuilder dialogContent: () -> Content) {
        _isPresented = isPresented
        self.dialogContent = dialogContent()
    }
```

I am getting a lot of issues on `DialogPresentation`.

[image: Here are some of the errors]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need to provide further detail, and a minimum reproducible example.  For instance: What issues?  What was `DialogContent `before?   Why are you trying to change to an `enum`?

Comment: Why are you publishing a `View` of all things? How did you even get to this point? This is most definitely an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Please explain what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: Nope, still don't understand what you are trying to achieve.  Sorry, but the whole approach of publishing a view in this way makes no sense to me.   Either it's too advanced to me to grok or the pattern is flawed.

Comment: I think @flanker, he wants to present a new View on change of Published variable.